# No error message when app stops working

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, logcat

I am currently developing an app, but when I start it and try to test my newly added features, the app just stops working and is killed, sending me to my home screen. Obviously something does not work. But why don't I get an error message in the Android Monitor of my Android Studio?

Comment: You probably set the AS to "show only selected application". If you switch to "no filters" and keep only "Warn" and higher error level, you will probably see the reason of the kill in logcat

Comment: Try to downgrade your new features, for testing purposes, even by commenting some lines, and see what happen. Best.

Comment: Prior to running your application, when the device is connected to your computer, when you select the Android Monitor, do you see your device in the dropdown at the top of the Android Monitor Window?  Your device might not be connected, in which case restarting Android Studio can sometimes fix that.  

If you see another device in that dropdown, for instance, an emulator you may have used before, then switch the drop down to your connected device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Proguard in Debug, nothing will appear. Additionally, if you are not using USB debugging and launching from Android Studio(or any other IDE) nothing will appear either. Check your proguard settings.

Also, only Logcat will show errors in Android Studio

Comment: I use USB debugging and launch via Android Studio, but running the app in debug mode or not, neither gives any error output.

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: I never used it actively. So I don't know. How can I check this?

Comment: `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` I'm sorry, I don't know Proguard. What does this mean?

Comment: Additionally, you have to use Logcat, not Android Monitor

Comment: That is not important. Above it is a boolean, `minifyEnabled`is it true or false

Comment: It is set to `false`. I really appreciate your help

Comment: False = no proguard. Are you using Logcat?

Comment: Yes, I am using Logcat, and I get the normal output while the app is running. But there is no error message when the app crashes.

Comment: Are you sure it crashes? If the app experiences ANRs it isn't reported. Is there a message on your screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116923/discussion-between-polarbear0106-and-jonas).